# Replacing shapefile with feature class in geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a shapefile which I turned to feature class to perform a rename on some fields.

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dty\Dty.shp', r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\gw\gb.gdb' )

#SET ENVIRONMENT TO THE GDB
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\gw\gb.gdb'
#rename
arcpy.AlterField_management('Dty','KYR_DATE1','KYR_DATE')

#Now turn this back and replace the initial shapefile
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion('Dty',r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dty')
```

last line doesn't replace the original shapefile, it creates `Dty_1.shp`
 What is the correct way?

Comment: I have done the renaming myself.I want only to replace the old shapefile with the new. I Updated the question with the rename. Can you make an answer with what you mean? Thanks

Comment: I think it is already there.

Comment: ok copy features and then? I would suggest to answer it so I can mark it as correct and better help viewers.

Comment: The function worked correctly but the date modified of the file hasn't changed to the new. I suppose it is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace an existing shapefile with another feature class with "**feature class to shapefile**", you need to first delete your existing shapefile with the **Delete_management** tool, otherwise the output will be renamed. Alternatively, you could  use the "**Copy Data**" as suggested by BERA, but then you have to set the overwrite environment to true.

So it should be :

```
path_gdb = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\gw\\gb.gdb\\"
path_shp = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\dty\\"

arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(path_shp + 'Dty.shp', path_gdb )

arcpy.AlterField_management(path_gdb + 'Dty','KYR_DATE1','KYR_DATE')
```

then, option 1

```
arcpy.env.workspace = path_shp
arcpy.Delete_management('Dty.shp')
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(path_gdb + 'Dty',path_shp)
```

or, option 2

```
arcpy.env.workspace = path_shp
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.Copy_management(path_gdb + 'Dty',path_shp)
```

Comment: it was set to true but the environment was in the gdb because it has to use the file in the gdb for the FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion.

Comment: Actually it isn't a typo. it is the name of the folder. I had tried with the name and it was giving _1 in the name so I used the folder name.

Comment: Only the copy solution worked and did the replacement. The other function won't do it. Have you tried it?

Comment: it says cannot create output Dty_1.shp

Comment: sorry, my mistake. featureClass creates new name if shapefile exists, in any case. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-shapefile.htm